# How to remove plotly.js x-axis tick label / button?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I don't know how it's called, maybe that's the reason why I didn't find anything in the plotly.js reference.
The label / button overlaps the regular x-axis labels and as seen in the screenshot is even cut off because it's not supposed to be there.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you have for the chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`hoverinfo`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#bar-hoverinfo).

> Any combination of "`x`", "`y`", "`z`", "`text`", "`name`" joined with a "`+`" > OR "`all`" or "`none`" or "`skip`".
>
> examples: "`x`", "`y`", "`x+y`", "`x+y+z`", "`all`"
>
> default: "`all`"
>
> Determines which trace information appear on hover. If
>   `none` or `skip` are set, no information is displayed upon hovering.
>   But, if `none` is set, click and hover events are still fired.

Setting it to `none` or `y` in your case should solve the problem.

```js
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  hoverinfo: 'y'
}];
Plotly.newPlot(document.getElementById("mydiv"), data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```